# Another cell decomposition of Klein bottle that gives another presentation for $\pi_1$ of Klein bottle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

The Klein bottle $K$ is the surface obtained from a square by gluing top and bottom sides by translation, and gluing left and right sides with a "twist". I can show that a presentation for the fundamental group is given by$$\pi_1(K, p) \cong \langle a, b \mid aba^{-1}b\rangle.$$What is another cell decomposition of $K$ with one polygon and one vertex that gives another presentation for the fundamental group as$$\pi_1(K, p) \cong \langle a, b \mid a^2 b^2\rangle?$$

Comment: It should be $ \pi_1(K, p) \cong \langle a, b \mid a^2b^2\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a square with all sides oriented in a counterclockwise fashion,  identified as $\ a,a,b,b. \ $ Of course the loop of the perimeter is $\ a^2 b^2 \ $ and goes to zero. To see this is the Klein bottle, just cut this square along the diagonal which connects the endpoint of the first $\ b \ $ to the endpoint of the first  $\ a. \ $ Call the diagonal $\ c: \ $ pasting along $\ a \ $ gives your presentation as $\ bc^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}: \ $

To see this drawn: my presentation

$$
\begin{array}{lcr}\ \  * \xleftarrow{ \qquad  b \qquad } * \\
b\Bigg\downarrow \qquad \searrow c \ \quad  \Bigg\uparrow a  \\
\ \  * \xrightarrow[ \qquad  a \qquad ]\ *   \end{array}
$$

goes to (glue lateral $\ a \ $ to bottom $\ a \ $ )

$$
\begin{array}{lcr}\ \  * \xrightarrow{ \qquad  c \qquad } * \\
b\Bigg\downarrow \qquad \nearrow a \ \quad  \Bigg\downarrow b  \\
\ \  * \xleftarrow[ \qquad  c \qquad ]\ *   \end{array}
$$

that is just classic Klein surface.